# ggplot2 barplot gradient fill

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've been recently dealing with barplots in ggplot environment and I can't seem to create gradient from left to right. It throws some sort of error regarding identity..

```
theTable <- within(data, 
                   Position <- factor(column1, 
                                      levels=names(sort(table(column1), 
                                                        decreasing=TRUE))))

ggplot(theTable, aes(x = factor(column1)))+
  geom_bar(color="black", alpha=0.3)+
  labs(x = "stuff1")+
  labs(y = "stuff2")+
  labs(title = "stuff3")+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=17),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"), title=element_text(size=20))+
  geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..),vjust=-1)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))#this doesn't work also
```

So I am trying to plot for example gradient, where max count would be dark and low count white, inbetwen shades of gray.

Comment: Please add `data` so this gets reproducibe.

Comment: scale_colour_gradient(low="black", high="white")